# How can I sort a list which is a class that has an attribute of id in id descending order?

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, collections, comparator

I have a class Product, that has a OneToMany relationship with another class called Feedback. I am doing a PostMapping to retrieve that class from my database to present it in a web view.  I am unable to figure out how to implement a comparator to sort my List fs in descending order.  The code thus far is below:

```
@PostMapping("/view/{id}")
    public ModelAndView addReview(@PathVariable("id") int id, @RequestParam("review") String review, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Product product = dao.findById(id).get();
        Feedback feedback = new Feedback(review);
        product.getFeedbacks().add(feedback);
        feedback.setProduct(product);
        dao.save(product);
        List<Feedback> fs = product.getFeedbacks();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("fs", fs);
        return new ModelAndView("/view").addObject("product", product);
    }
```

How can I sort my fs based on the id which is the primary key in descending order?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try by making a FeedbackSorter

```
class FeedbackSorter implements Comparator<Feedback> 
{ 
    public int compare(Feedback a, Feedback b) 
    { 
        return a.getProduct().getID() - b.getProduct().getID()
    } 
}
```

Then
Collections.sort(fs,  new FeedbackSorter ());

Comment: perfect just made a change to b.getId() - a.getId() and had to add the class within controller package and it worked

Answer (score 1):

1.Add the interface comparable to your object.

```
Public class  Feedback implements Comparable<Feedback>
```

2 override compareTo method

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Feedback o) {
    return this.getId().compareTo(o.getId());
}
```

3. Use collections to sort the list.

3.1Feedback ids in ascending order

Collections.sort(fs);

3.2 Feedback ids in reverse order

Collections.sort(fs, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: this seems like it should have worked as well, but kept getting can't resolve to int type, and I could not figure out why I was getting that error